# Using JSX in a React-Native project

Tags: react-native, jsx, tsx, react-templates

Nevertheless, always that I initialize my project by doing:

```
npx react-native@latest init AwesomeProject
```

, it produces App.tsx file. I have changed it to App.jsx and it works perfectly but I am not sure that this is the right way to do it. It executes perfectly, but I am not sure if this is the correct way to do it. I just feel more comfortable developing in javascript (I have any idea of TypeScript :( ).

Answer (score 1):

Follow the [official documents](https://reactnative.dev/docs/typescript#using-javascript-instead-of-typescript):

> React Native defaults new applications to TypeScript, but JavaScript may still be used. Files with a .jsx extension are treated as JavaScript instead of TypeScript, and will not be typechecked. JavaScript modules may still be imported by TypeScript modules, along with the reverse.

So if you create new app by `npx react-native@latest init AwesomeProject`, `App.tsx` will be created. But if you don't want to use `typescript` in your project, you can just change from `App.tsx` to `App.jsx` and everything ok